# Delaying some records in a Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a consumer project that consumes data from a Kafka topic. 90% of the data in that stream can be processed in real-time but for specific records (~10%) I need to delay the processing.

Should I have two separate consumers in same JVM and consume 90% of the records in one consumer and ignore the 10% and let other consumer to take care of it or push 10% of the messages to another topic and delay the processing of the other topic?

It would be great if I could have a single consumer and two checkpointing mechanisms one for 90% and the other one delayed by 10% but the Kafka client doesn't seem to support this use-case. It would help me to avoid any unnecessary deserialization and network IO.

Comment: what do you mean by "specific records"? Some special field in them?
Also, what do you mean by "delay the process?"

As you said, if they are not representing the same event, the most logical is to produce those data in another topic and consume it accordingly.

An other way is to have the consumer simply read the data and transfer them to some worker. You would then have two workers: one for real time, one for delayed message. No problem in reading them early.

I may not have clearly understand your needs, do not hesitate to give some details

Comment: @Treziac we're processing event data and storing them in micro batches each minute. If the event timestamp is from previous days (~10% records), we need to delay the processing and have larger batches for historical data. I think using the same consumer and transferring them to another worker may not be a good idea because the data needs to be in-memory for more than 15 minutes (delaying) and we can't commit the checkpoints in this process. Also, I do not have any control on how the data is produced so I either need to push to messages to another topic or have two consumers for each use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have multiple checkpoint for a single consumer - either use two consumers or two topics.

- One problem with two consumers is that all messages would be read twice, not at the exact same time, which pose the issue to know when a message is historical and when it is not : what happen if a message procuced this day is read at 23:59:59 by one consumer and 00:00:01 by the other (same issu with relative time). You could use some hysteresis and monitor lag to prevent this issue.
- Separate your data in two topics. You can use kafka stream or any other stream processing tool for that. For example your `events` topic would be processed and separated in two topics `historical-events` and `realtime-events`. You would still have two consumers, but not on the same topics. As you proposed, you could also just consume your `events` topic, treat immediate data and send historical data to an other topic (so you have two topics instead of three, and no problem for committed offset) - but this mean more IO for the process client, and two responsibilities for the client

  As you have only one consumer reading each message from the base topic, it will always be either recent or historical, so you won't have the previous issue.
- Only one consumer which treat message accordingly, but as you pointed out, it is problematic with offset commiting and could use much RAM given your historical batch. Concerning offset commiting, you could simply store (in an other kafka compacted topic is the same way than _consumer_offset does) the last offset regarding your historical or current offset, and when restarting, resume from your historical batch, and ignore all "recent" data until you reach the correct offset. This is possible, but use more RAM, and way more troublesome.

Your choice highly depends on what is problematic for you (IO, RAM, simply have a correct behaviour). Separating in two topics from the start is probably the easiest to implement, can be done in a separate process, efficiently separates the responsibility of each process, and will minimize the impact on the processing client.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed great response! I guess I will go with the seperate topic approach but one last question: Is there performance improvement that we can do by pushing the data to other topic in micro-batches or using a simple producer and decoupling the records one by one is the simplest and most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Most kafka clients (given proper conf) send data in batches. Ie, if you ask a client to produce 100 messages in 500ms, it will not send 100 individuals message but a single batch of 100 message (if you set linger.ms > 500ms). Well, actually, it will send one message to each necessary broker (if you have three brokers, and you send data to a topic whose partitions are distributed among those three brokers, you will send 3 message)
Your consumer should commit offset only once the data is effectively send from producer. Kafka stream /  apache flink / etc deal with all this natively

Comment: Thanks for taking time for answering my question. @Treziac